# Using regression fit to compare two groups at a time point

Tags: r, regression, t-test

I have estimated a regression model in R with two groups, included as factors. Their regression fits are visually quite different, but I would like to statistically test if they are different on a specific day (Day T).

I have used the predict function to obtain the fitted values and their standard errors on Day T. Can I use these values to perform a t-test, and if so, what degrees of freedom should I use?

Comment: How did you work out which day you wanted to test?

Comment: This is medical data. There is a date at which it is expected that the treatment group will be stabilized. Visually it has (its curve is much lower and flatter from that day on. In contrast, the untreated group still shows a negative slow, which in this context means it is still recovering.

Comment: So you figured out which day to test by looking at the data?

Comment: Looking at the data more or less confirms their expectation.

Comment: They expected it to be recovered about twice as fast as the control group, which looks recovered at the end of the measurement period. But yes, there is an element of the data informing my choice of the day...

Comment: I should clarify that the day i am interested in testing is about half way through the period. But in principle I am curious about a test for any given day.